# T-SQL SEQUENCE runs out, no cycle, what happens?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My particular case is that I'm writing a unit test and I want to simulate an error for a sequence generator, but I can't find any documentation on what it does when it runs out.

Here, of course, is the documentation for SEQUENCE:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

It, very nicely, says everything about it, except:  what happens if I run out.

Consider the case when I set the sequence to a very small value (1-10) and I "know" that it will never go over 10.  Except there's a bug in the code, and it suddenly gets every last one... then asks for one more?

Hypothetical example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[MY_SEQUENCE] 
 AS [tinyint]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 10
 NO CYCLE
 CACHE
```

External code asks for the 11th one.

```
 SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR MY_SEQUENCE
```

What happens?

Comment: Ehm... run your example and see it for yourself?

Comment: What are you expecting.. It will throw error once it reach maxvalue.. The sequence object 'MY_SEQUENCE' has reached its minimum or maximum value. Restart the sequence object to allow new values to be generated.

Comment: It seriously took you longer to type up a question than it would have to just run this and witness what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, my work does not let me have my own copy of SQL Server...  I was hoping to know what the error code was.  (And I would need to submit a request to get a database to play with... which would take longer than typing this.)

Comment: You don't have a dev database where you can experiment with stuff? You can always use sql fiddle too. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8dff

Comment: 1: buy laptop.  2: install SQL Server Developer Edition.  3: profit.

Comment: Kindly use  online or own development environment to play with code.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you mentioned specifies what happens: "[...] throw an exception when its minimum or maximum value is exceeded"

Regarding the error message you can find out using a simple Google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=t-sql+error+messages+sequence The fourth link is https://www.sqlshack.com/sequence-objects-in-sql-server/ and there you can find a screenshot of the error, which has the number 11728.

Of course, it would be easier to try it yourself, using one of the methods already specified in the comments.